# Do I need the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin installed to use WordPress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns, multisite

Have been trying to setup and configure WordPress Multisites on my domain.
I have installed and activated the "Sub Domain" install.

I am simply looking to create site likes this.

**Main website:**

http://www.example.com

**Sub Domain Sites:**

http://docs.example.com

http://demo.example.com

So far I have created the sub domain http://docs.example.com in the WordPress Dashboard. To be able to access the WordPress Dashboard for this sub domain I had to create a sub domain in cPanel that pointed `docs` to the `public_html` directory. Also in my VPS.net hosting panel I had to create an `A Record` for `docs` pointing to the IP address of my server

My issue is that when I try and view http://docs.example.com in a web browser I always get a blank white screen.

Do I need the WordPress MU Domain Mapping plugin installed to use WordPress Multisite. I have installed it previously but it didn't make a difference.

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I believe you might find more relevant help in the Wordpress forums, as this site is more skewed towards programming-related questions.

Comment: Yeah, have tried there as well. No responses. I thought it might be a DNS related issue. Been trying for almost a week now to get this sorted. Clutching at straws.

Comment: It is unlikely a DNS issue if you get a blank white screen. Your browser would have produced some sort of error message if it were DNS-related. You can use the network inspector to check the HTTP status code returned. Also check your PHP error logs.

Comment: Thanks @shrm Here is the actual site address: http://docs.wpinsite.com/ HTTP status codes returned 200 and error logs are empty.

Comment: Seems to show up fine over here! Try clearing your DNS & browser cache?